# Web Responsive Issue on Mobile Chrome

Tags: css, responsive

I was check responsivity of my website on inspect element especially for sidemenu from `bootstrap.css` and its worked well, but when i tried check responsivity in my mobile chrome its look like messed up. I dont get it anyone can give me a suggest?

**Device toolbar** in inspect:

[image]

**Mobile Chrome**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is obvious. I have listed a few reasons why this problem arises:

1. May be the height and width of your phone and the height and width of the screen you are viewing on chrome is different.
2. Sometimes Google developer tool does not show the accurate results. Try zooming in or zooming out.
3. There can be some problems with your CSS. Recheck your CSS.

All I will say is that it will be better you to test your site on your phone rather than using Chrome Developer tools.

Comment: i have check in another browser app in my phone, its worked well but not for chrome